# fast jpeg compression android, hardware support?

Tags: android, image, compression, jpeg

I understand the popular Qualcomm Snapdragon chipsets provide hardware support for fast jpeg compression.  Does anyone know how to access this and what performance you see?

The Bitmap.compress method takes over 50 ms to compress a 720p RGBA image.  This is similar to software speeds (libjpegTurbo).  So I don't this is taking advantage of hardware acceleration.

It may be that this requires using the Snapdragon DSP device, probably using OpenMAX.  Does anyone know?

Comment: https://developer.qualcomm.com/download/snapdragon-sdk.zip need access with an account though

Comment: and where does this relate to the question of fast jpeg compression?

Comment: Qualcomm provides a custom LLVM C++ compiler; they [claim](https://developer.qualcomm.com/software/snapdragon-llvm-compiler-android) to achieve 10% improvement in JPEG compression. But this is not a HW encoder, unfortunately. If [MediaCodec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html) on your device does not support JPEG encoder (and most likely, it doesn't), you will not find this codec with [OpenMAX IL](https://source.android.com/devices/media/#expose).